# How to speed up ogr2ogr process on giant geodatabase

Tags: ogr, ogr2ogr

I have a geodatabase that has over 193 million polygons.

I have a process that gets a small subset of this .gdb based on an inputs' extent, for thousands of inputs, using ogr2ogr.

I am looking for ways to speed this up. I am testing for one input right now, and the ogr2ogr step has taken over 25 minutes and counting, which means my entire process will take far longer than I need it to. I am hoping there has to be a way to speed this up.

Here is my test command that took almost 30 minutes to run:
ogr2ogr -clipsrc -102.38428516 54.5384116051 -102.031403056 54.7529375968 -spat -102.38428516 54.5384116051 -102.031403056 54.7529375968 -f "ESRI Shapefile"   -t_srs EPSG:32613

I found this [thread](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5460), but it seems that they already implemented PG_USE_COPY=YES as the default.

Some system info:

236 GB RAM / 16 CPUs: Intel Core Processor (Skylake, IBRS)

Despite the impression I got from the thread I linked, adding --config PG_USE_COPY YES sped the process up from ~30 minutes to < 15. I would like to speed this up even more by utilizing PostGIS or something similar but have no idea what I'm doing with that, so for now I guess this will do.

Comment: Transfer the data to a postgis dB and add an index

Comment: Thank you for your comment @IanTurton. Can you expand on what you mean or point me to resources where I can learn how to implement that?

Comment: from the link you provide that discusses how to put the data into a postgis database

Comment: The reverse engineered OpenfileGDB https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/openfilegdb.html has a limited support for using spatial indexes. Import into PostGIS is a good suggestion but GeoPackage could do as well. Conversion simply: `ogr2ogr -f gpkg output.gpkg input.gdb`.